# Merge 2 lists except duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have another question for you.
I have to merge 2 lists excluding duplicates.

This is my code:

```
private List<BudgetCommessa> UnisciListeSenzaDuplicati(List<BudgetCommessa> p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente, List<BudgetCommessa> listBudgetCommessaDaAggiungere)
{
    //restituisco lista verificata senza doppioni
    //List<BudgetCommessa> listaUnita = new List<BudgetCommessa>();

    List<BudgetCommessa> listaUnita = 
    p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente.Concat(listBudgetCommessaDaAggiungere.Except(p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente)).ToList();
    /*p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente.Union(listBudgetCommessaDaAggiungere).ToList();*/

    return listaUnita;
}
```

I've tried also:

```
List<BudgetCommessa> listaUnita = 
p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente.Union(listBudgetCommessaDaAggiungere)
                             .Distinct().ToList();
```

and:

```
List<BudgetCommessa> listaUnita = 
p_listBudgetCommessaEsistente.Union(listBudgetCommessaDaAggiungere).ToList();
```

(supposing that the Union() method already excludes duplicate rows)

Comment: And what is your problem with Union()?

Comment: Does `BudgetCommessa` implement equals properly? If not, there's the issue.

Comment: You are showing what you've tried, but did  it work? If not, what didn't work as expected?

Comment: How are you defining duplicate?  Same object reference, or equal member values?

Comment: `Union` does remove duplicates.  There's no point in calling `Distinct` after it.

Comment: What's your definition of Distinct/Duplicate?

Comment: @servy Yes. the problem is that it STILL SHOWS DUPLICATES

Comment: @TimSchmelter it doesn't works because, in every of three cases, it still shows duplicates

Comment: Please include a sample run with input, wrong outputs, and what the output should look like.

Answer (score -1):

The class you're poutting in the list must  override Equals and GetHashCode. I think implementing IEquatable or IEqualityComparer might work too.

Comment: It needs sensible implementations of both `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.  `IComparable` doesn't provide that, it's `IEquatable` or `IEqualityComparer` that does.

Comment: Again, you're missing the key point here; it needs a sensible implementation of `GetHashCode` as well, an those interfaces are what define that (although you don't need to define the interfaces; you can just override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @Servy I've updated my answer again.  You can edit my response if its not to your liking.